# How to keep underscores in Python within a word boundary?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-table

When writing code in `python-mode` my preference would be to include underscores within a word boundary, so `variable_with_underscores` is treated as a single word.

How would I limit my word preference only to `python-mode`?

Comment: Depending on your use cases it might be enough to switch to balanced-expressions based stuff like `mark-sexp` instead of `mark-word`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a hook to modify the `python-mode-syntax-table`:

```el
;; Keep underscores within a word boundary
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda () (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" python-mode-syntax-table)))
```

Answer (score 5):

It's bird, it's a plane, it's `superword-mode`:

> Superword mode is a buffer-local minor mode.  Enabling it changes
>   the definition of words such that symbols characters are treated
>   as parts of words: e.g., in ‘superword-mode’,
>   "this_is_a_symbol" counts as one word.

It's a minor mode, so you can set it in a hook the normal way: `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'superword-mode)`.  `superword-mode` has only existed since 24.4, so you'll need to hack the syntax table by hand in older versions.

I find it very convenient to bind this to a key so I can easily toggle it.  It's the sort thing I want sometimes, but not others.

Comment: This might work for navigation but for "replace-string" does not work. Say you want to replace just one word `C-u M-x replace-string` this won't work. The accepted answer however, does the trick.